# Recon testing sessions

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, exploratory

I've recently stumbled upon a new term I have not heard before - "Recon testing sessions" - from what I understand these are the very first manual testing sessions of a software when one learns about the software and generate ideas for future exploratory tests.

What things to look for and note, what techniques and strategies can be used for Recon testing sessions?

Comment: Recon is military term for investigation. So it is same as Investigative testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recon testing/Reconnaissance is the act of gathering preliminary data or intelligence on your target. this is the first phase of penetration testing.The data is gathered in order to better plan for your attack. Reconnaissance can be performed actively or passively.

below mentioned areas are keys of Recon testing sessions;

*The ecosystem in which the software under test resides.
Touchpoints to other systems.
Variables (things we change or can change).
Obvious vulnerabilities and potential risks.*

Answer (score 1):

Recon testing is the session for collecting initial data and it will help in penetration testing. It can be done manually or automated.